# Where can I find the Mac Office 2011 developer details?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I'm wanting to learn about the API and add-on capability of the Mac version of Office, 2011.
I cannot find any documentation on MSDN - it must be hidden well. Can someone point me at it please? Thank you.

Comment: Seems documentation is not available, the only options would be to use VBA or AppleScript (http://www.officeformac.com/ms/ProductForums/Word/11870)

Comment: @0xA3 If you could point me at the VBA or Applescript documentation, that would be fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the the Mac Office 2011 VBA reference docs at http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/default.aspx?src=office.

In almost all cases, the PC version of Office 2010 VBA references are concurrent with the Mac Office 2011 versions, but you can locate the **Object Model Changes from Microsoft** - *Product* - **2010** on each product under the *Visual Basic Help* page and you'll see what may have been added, removed or changed. For example, here is the [Object Model Changes from Microsoft Word 2010](http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/Word/html/womscChangesBetweenWord2010and2011.htm).

Comment: Both links now redirect to http://www.microsoft.com/mac