# VBA Add-In Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, macos, menu, add-in

I have a fully functional Macro that I'm trying to convert to an Add-In so I can use it on all excel documents. However I can't get it create a menu. Please Help.

First Things First:

I'm using Office 2011-Excel on a Mac running Mountain Lion

My .xlam file is saved in the correct folder Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Add-Ins

I've installed it correctly using the Tools/Add-Ins menu

My code is in the This Worksheet section of the .xlam file

My Add-In's source code is viewable from all documents

My code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim cControl As CommandBarButton

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

On Error Resume Next 'Just in case

    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("P Wave").Delete 'Delete any existing menu item that may have been left.
    Set cControl = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add 'Add the new menu item and Set a CommandBarButton Variable to it

        With cControl 'Work with the Variable
            .Caption = "P Wave"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "runSheet()"
            'Macro stored in a Standard Module
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next 'In case it has already gone.

    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("P Wave").Delete

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I can't get my Macro menu to appear. Please help

Comment: The sad reason is that you can't tweak command bars with VBA in Excel 2011. This is one of the many compatibility problems with Excel 2011.

Comment: ****(swearing), what would be a good work around then. I need some sort of easily accessible way to execute my Sub on command. I need something that is compatible with as many versions of Excel as possible and can be easily handled by a neanderthal.

Comment: I don't have any experience with it my self, but here is an example of method that may be suitable to you: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/addins/macvbamenu.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add your command buttons, or even your own Tab, on the Ribbon although you may have to learn a bit about RibbonX XML.  It will give compatibility back to Excel 2007 (I think).

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705(v=office.14).aspx) may get you started.

Also, [This visual designer](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm) may be more exciting to get you going.  I haven't used it but Andy Pope is the man on all things VBA!

Comment: This question is regarding Excel 2011 for Mac. It is not possible to edit the ribbon by XML in this version.

Comment: OK thank you - missed that. You could check out VMWare.

Comment: Hold the press, I can defiantly create a menu on the command bar using VBA by running a macro. Its just when I turn my "Macro" into an "Add-Inn" that the menu creation fails. Just checking to make sure that's what everyones saying. Editing the ribbon is also not working for an "Add-In"

Comment: I just tested it some more. It looks like the only thing not working is `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` and `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()` Also `Option Explicit` seems to deactivate the code all together

Comment: You probably need to check out the VBA object model for the Mac, what's in, what's out  etc.  Try this link to get started perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071171/where-can-i-find-the-mac-office-2011-developer-details OR THIS which deals with the Ribbon specifically http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/mac-word-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA102927321.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103526326

Comment: Thanks, but I took a look at all of the object changes on office 2010 (which according to those references should be the same as 2011), nothing that would cause Workbook_Open() to fail. I'm going to move this under a new question to focus solely on why Workbook_Open() would fail. I think this will better reflect the scope of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408113/workbook-open-wont-execute-excel-2011