# Workbook_Open() won't execute Excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2011 (should be same as Excel 2010)

Code is under the "ThisWorkbook" module in Excel

Events are enabled

Macros are enabled

I can't seem to get either `Workbook_Open()` or `Workbook_BeforeClose()` to execute. I've read numerous posts on the subject but no solution. Here is some simple test code that should execute but doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveSheet.Range("BL4").Value = "Open is working"
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next 'in case the menu item has already been deleted
    ActiveSheet.Range("BL5").Value = "Close is working"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you comment out `On Error Resume Next`? Try adding `MsgBox "Hello"` to both events to see if at least a message will be displayed.

Comment: Did you mean to say 'ThisWorkBook' not 'ThisSheet'?

Comment: They can be private. It will make no difference.

Comment: Did you put these in the Workbook object or in a separate module?

Comment: They (i) must be in the workbook-level module (called ThisWorkbook unless you've renamed it) and (ii) macros must be enabled. Then it *will* work.

Comment: Typo. It's in the workbook level module. All apologies I'll edit the question. The question still stands

Comment: Just for completeness, your code works fine for me on a Windows 7 PC running Excel 2013 and on my MacBook Pro also running Excel 2013 under OS X.  Just a silly thought but which nearly threw me.  You are looking at the right cells BL4 and 5 are off screen to the right?

Comment: I thought the same thing, Barry.  BL is column 64, not a convenient area for debugging cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have put this in this in the right place and have macros enabled.

Then, try adding this line to the workbook_open method:

```
MsgBox "HELLO"
```

Do you see the msg box? You're choice of cell looks a bit strange

Also, I think you need to use a .xlsm file not .xlsx (Although not sure on that one)

FInally, if a plugin calls something like this line, it could cause your events not to fire..

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

So make sure you have tested it with no other sheets or addins open.

Comment: Bravo, the `MsgBox` works. So why don't my other statements execute. Like writing to a cell. Why isn't that working. What am I missing?

Comment: Based on the msgbox working, I am certain they do execute. You are writing to cell "BL4" Which you have to scroll very far right to see. Did you mean to put "B4"??

Comment: Don't know why, but this is working today. I'm not sure what changed, but now it works. Thanks to all.