# Is it possible to read document text in an open Word window programmatically on OSX?

Tags: cocoa, ms-word, accessibility, osx-mavericks, macos-carbon

Is it possible to read and write text into an open Microsoft Word document using another app? How can it be done?

My OS is OSX.

Comment: Yeah probably using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071171/where-can-i-find-the-mac-office-2011-developer-details).

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Accessibilty APIs and the surprisingly good AppleScript support from Microsoft Office for Mac will get you a long way.